# Clicking on the menu does not work

Tags: android, listview, actionbarsherlock, lazy-loading

I use **ActionBarSherlock** for navigation in application and it work fine everywhere, except one activity what consist `ExpandableListView` with list of *big images*. For loading images I use *LazyList*. 
But when I quickly scroll list, images begin loading and clicking on the menu does not work - menu drops but no reaction on click. Also this behavior remains after imagel loading done. I can only press back button and come to this activity again, than all works fine.
Every time when I click to "frosen" menu I can see in **logcat** messages as:

```
02-06 12:06:38.314: WARN/EGL_emulation(2043): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-06 12:06:38.963: WARN/InputMethodManagerService(998): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@afa7b270 attribute=null
```

Problem occurs on the device and on the simulator. How to fix it?

Comment: From where you are getting  big images

Comment: I getting big images from website, but I use LazyList - it show default picture until images will be loaded on the cd card.

Comment: then you should use asynchronous task.It may work

Comment: I used ExecutorService and submit Runnable to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Menu was "frozen" because `onNavigationItemSelected` in **ActionBarSherlock** was not called. I found the cause of the problem but do not know how it is interconnected. 
I show `ListView` with few items with default images. When real images download finished they replace default images, but they have another size (bigger) and something goes wrong after. I solved the problem by setting a predetermined height of the images.